# Guardar en una variable con formato json el recorrido de un while

Tags: php, array, json

** cuando imprimo si me trae mis datos, ahora quiero guardarlos en formato json para consumirlos en un web services**

```
`$query = "SELECT datos FROM conCreditoEmpresariasWS WHERE bandera IS NULL";

$result = odbc_exec($conexionDB,$query)
or die(mysql_error());
                     
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) {    
    print_r($row);                           
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Así lo podrías hacer:

```
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {              
$x = json_decode($row['datos']);         
$datos = $x->datos;
}
print_r($datos);
```

Comment: Por favor, trata de explicar el código, ya que siempre será útil para nuevos usuarios saber una explicación detallada de cada parte del código, asimismo incluir referencias, por ejemplo de la función [`odbc_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php), aunque para usuarios experimentados parezca que no necesita una explicación, para nuevos usuarios es útil encontrarla.